# Combining multiple Dataframes in pandas with common column names

Tags: pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have 7 dataframes which look like this:

```
name sub amount
a     b    5

name sub amount
a     b    10

name sub amount
a     b    63

name sub amount
a     b    85

name sub amount
a     b    4
```

.
.
.

I want them to look like this:

```
amount
5
10
63
85
4
.
.
```

i tried:

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

but the result shows diagonal combined dataframes with nan.

anyone who can help?

Comment: `pd.concat([d['amount'] for d in frames])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
frames = [df1['amount'], df2['amount'], df3['amount'], df4['amount'], df5['amount'], df6['amount'], df7['amount']]
result = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `ignore_index=True` should not be needed if the DataFrames look like specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a'], 'sub': ['b'], 'amount': [5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a'], 'sub': ['b'], 'amount': [10]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a'], 'sub': ['b'], 'amount': [63]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a'], 'sub': ['b'], 'amount': [85]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a'], 'sub': ['b'], 'amount': [4]})

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]).amount
```